# Different results of Griffin-Lim from librosa and torchaudio

Tags: python, pytorch, librosa, torchaudio

I'm trying to transform the spectrogram back to the audio. First I used `librosa.griffinlim` and it worked well, but it was time-consuming. Therefore I am trying to use torchaudio on GPU to boost the transformation. However I obtained different reconstruction results compared to the librosa.

This is my code:

```
# Preprocess
data, fs = librosa.load('waveform.wav', sr=44100)
b, a = signal.butter(3, [20 / fs, 1000 / fs], 'bandpass')
data = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
plt.plot(data)

# STFT
DMatrix = librosa.stft(data, n_fft=2048, hop_length=int(2048 * 0.1), window='hann')
dbMatrix = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(DMatrix), ref=np.max)
```

[The original waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLwzW.png)

And I obtained results similar to the original waveform using librosa:

```
spec = librosa.db_to_amplitude(dbMatrix)
re_wav = librosa.griffinlim(spec, n_iter=100, n_fft=2048, hop_length=int(2048 * 0.1), window='hann')
plt.plot(re_wav)
```

[librosa reconstruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV371.png)

But when I changed to torchaudio, the result is different.

```
griffinlim = torchaudio.transforms.GriffinLim(n_fft=2048, n_iter=100, hop_length=int(2048 * 0.1)).to('cuda')
spec = librosa.db_to_amplitude(dbMatrix)
re_wav = griffinlim(torch.tensor(spec).to('cuda'))
plt.plot(re_wav.cpu().detach().numpy())
```

[torchaudio reconstruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTGzi.png)

What am I missing?

Comment: The result is different how?

Comment: @JonNordby I have added images of the result in the question.

Comment: Can you describe the differences that you hear? Also, can you provide spectrogram plots of the reconstructed waveform? That would be much more informative than waveform

Comment: torchaudio GriffinLim has default power=2, which is for power spectrogram as input. Try setting power=1 for amplitude

Comment: @JonNordby Sorry for the late reply. The difference is that torchaudio's reconstruction sounds mostly noise. And setting power=1 works for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great to hear. I have added it as an answer now. It would be great if you could accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three common representations for the values in a magnitude spectrogram: amplitude, power and decibel. The Griffin-Lim transform must be aware of this when converting back to a waveform.
When using `spec = librosa.db_to_amplitude(dbMatrix)`, the result is an amplitude spectrogram.
In `librosa.griffinlim` the default is for an amplitude spectrogram, so you get a good reconstruction.

For `torchaudio.transforms.GriffinLim` the default is for a power spectrogram. In order make it work with an amplitude spectrogram, pass the argument `power=1`.

Comment: By the way, I also noticed that the amplitude decreases after the inverse transformation. I would like to ask how to obtain the correct amplitude.